# For what functions does the inequality hold?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, inequality

Let us assume that function $f:\mathbb{R}^{+}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$ satisfies
$$
\left|\frac{d^k f}{dx^k}\right|<\frac{C}{1+x^k}
$$
for $k=0,1,2$ and some $C>0$.

Let $g(x)=f(x)-v(x)$, where $v(x)$ is an unknown function.

I wonder about condition for $v(x)$ that guarantees that
$$
\left|\frac{d^k g}{dx^k}\right|<\frac{D}{1+x^k}
$$
for $k=0,1,2$ and some $D>0$.

I know that I can use the triangle inequality, then:
$$
\left|\frac{d^k g}{dx^k}\right| < \left|\frac{d^k f}{dx^k}\right| + \left|\frac{d^k v}{dx^k}\right|
$$

and now I can say that $\left|\frac{d^k v}{dx^k}\right|<\frac{D}{1+x^k}$ is enough condition that I need.

My question is: Can I generalize this condition to receive only conditions on $v(x)$ function.

I suppose it can be the following one:

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} v(x) = const.
$$

Comment: For $f=0$ you have $g=-v$, therefore I do not think that the condition $\left|\frac{d^k v}{dx^k}\right|<\frac{D}{1+x^k}$ (for all $k$) can be improved.

Comment: But $f$ can take only positive values, so it can not be equal to $0$.

Comment: Then choose $f(x) = 1$.

Comment: Ok, you are right. What if I assume that $f$ is decreasing?

Answer (score 1):

We have $v=f-g$. Tren
$$
v^{(k)}(x)=f^{(k)}(x)-g^{(k)}(x).
$$
This shows that $v$ satisfies the same condition as $f$ and $g$ with constant $C+D$.